# transform: translateY(-50%) --- Chrome "invalid property value" error, why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, css-transforms

Chrome is giving me an "invalid property value" for `transform: translateY(-50%)`. I've used the necessary vendor prefixes. There are no problems in other browsers.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
In case it's helpful, here's the context (using Sass indented syntax):

```
.modal
  background: #fefefe
  border: $modal--util solid 1px
  border-radius: 2px
  left: 0 
  right: 0
  margin-left: auto
  margin-right: auto
  z-index: 12
  max-width: 380px
  overflow: hidden
  visibility: hidden
  position: fixed
  top: 50%
  transform: translateY(-50%)
```

Comment: Please check your error once again, its working fine at my side. Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b0vgajoq/

Comment: [**works fine**](http://jsfiddle.net/h3domt73/2/) `transform:translatey(-50%);` please check your code

Comment: Checked, rechecked, and continue to recheck. Either I'm going blind or there's something funny going on... I'll update the question with my full css selector declaration in case someone can spot the problem.

Comment: Where are the semi-colons? Are you using Sass or something?

Comment: I'm using Sass indented syntax. Should have mentioned that :)

Comment: @IsaacGregson Please also check the CSS output.

Comment: The output seems fine: transform: translateY(-50%); in the inspector and the compiled file.

Comment: Also note that the vendor prefix `-webkit-` of `transform` property [is needed](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) for Chrome 35 and olders.

Comment: When I inspect the elements in the above fiddles I see the same error... seems there's a bug in my install of Chrome. Hmmm... puzzling. I'm on Arch Linux... thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalled and re-installed Chrome and the problem's gone... I think Chrome wasn't auto-updating (I'm on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Found this after experiencing the same kind of problem. I had copied a value from Windows' calculator. In my IDE everything looked okay: `transform: translateY(-‭85.71428571428574‬%)`. However when deploying the code the decimal was inserted as `&#8237;`. Thus the actual value that was getting to the browser was `transform: translateY(-&#8237;‭85.71428571428574‬%)`.

After manually entering the value the problem went away.

I hope this helps somebody who might stumble upon this after going through the same problem.